# Chrome Extension: MessageSender parameter is empty

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We publish an extension on the Chrome store (unlisted). 
The extension uses Native Messaging and connects to the host.
A few days ago the callback function which is a parameter of **chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function callback)** stopped returning the MessageSender parameter from the native code. The MessageSender parameter returns empty.

This causes a loss of communication between the extension and the host (native code).
The extension stopped working and we started to get error messaged that the port is disconnected.

Does any one know the root cause ?
Was there a change in the implementation of this mechanism ?

Many thanks !
Sharona.

Comment: onMessage cannot receive anything from the native host. See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-client): you need a port opened via connectNative to receive messages.

Comment: Yes, I do have a port opened. The callback function of the onMessage listener is in the format of: receiveFromNative(response, sender). The sender returns empty. All of a sudden in Chrome 72.

Comment: If it's a bug or a change in the browser it might have been already reported on https://crbug.com. Otherwise do note we can't help you without seeing [MCVE](/help/mcve) at least.

Comment: Our extension is not listed. I would be happy to demonstrate privately. In any case I opened a bug in crbug.com.